# Problem while publishing Flutter app on AppStore

Tags: flutter

I complete my flutter app and ready to publish on app store but i receive rejected and reason was in this message

```
Guideline 2.1 - Performance - App Completeness

We discovered one or more bugs in your app when reviewed on iPad running iOS 13.3.1 on Wi-Fi.
```

Comment: Can you post full email you received from them?

Comment: Next Steps

To resolve this issue, please run your app on a device to identify any issues, then revise and resubmit your app for review.

If we misunderstood the intended behavior of your app, please reply to this message in Resolution Center to provide information on how these features were intended to work.

For new apps, uninstall all previous versions of your app from a device, then install and follow the steps to reproduce the issue. For updates, install the new version as an update to the previous version, then follow the steps to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Can you show a video recording of your app, I think there is some issue in your UX part.